# How to select a dynamic date with SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql, date, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure to generate a delivery day when a customer requests it.
Depending on the zone of the customer it outputs the delivery day.

But now I also want to add date to it. So it not only output what day, but also the date on that day in the upcoming week.

This is what my stored procedure looks like now (customerId is my IN parameter)

```
BEGIN
SELECT
    CASE customer_zone
    WHEN 1 THEN 'monday'
    WHEN 2 THEN 'tuesday'
    WHEN 3 THEN 'wednesday'
    WHEN 4 THEN 'thursday'
    WHEN 5 THEN 'friday'
    ELSE 'unknown'
    END
FROM customer
WHERE customer_id = customerId;
END
```

It works fine, but I really don't know how to handle the date feature - I guess I can use the now() function and add some number to it according to the relative day?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your customer_zone is a number from 1 to 5. Perhaps you can simply add the customer_zone to `NOW()` or `CURRENT_DATE()` to get the relative date. Something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL customer_zone DAY) AS my_date
FROM customer
```

Comment: yes zone is a number from 1-5 based on the customer location. What do you mean by add the customer_zone to now()?

Comment: i see - i dont know DATE_ADD, what is that?

Comment: @MacLuc It's a MySQL function that adds a value (e.g. days) to a date. Are you not using MySQL?

Comment: Yes im using MySQL, just didnt know the function

Comment: @MacLuc You can either use `ADDDATE()` or `DATE_ADD()`, they're synonyms. Check [MySQL docs here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate).

Answer (score 0):

The first Monday in the future is always

```
  dateadd(d,datediff(d,'1900-01-01',getdate())/7*7+7,'1900-01-01')
```

You can add (customer_zone - 1) days to this to get the first M/T/W/T/F for customer_zone 1/2/3/4/5. Depending on your SQL implementation, you may need now(), today(), etc., instead of getdate().

```
  dateadd(d,datediff(d,'1900-01-01',getdate())/7*7+7+customer_zone-1,'1900-01-01')
```

If you [google SQL with "next monday"](https://www.google.com/search?q=SQL%20%22next%20monday%22&oq=SQL%20%22next%20monday%22), you'll find a lot of useful stuff.